# mysql queries execute in sequence instead of simultaneously using async wait in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, async-await

I have sequence of mysql queries.First query result used in another query and so on.Therefore, I want to execute queries in sequence.The code is been separated using different methods.But this works simultaneously due to asynchronous behaviour.

I tried simple code using `dountil`, `async.forever`, `waterfall` and `series` all works well without mysql. But when I add mysql code , its doesn't work properly due to asynchronous behavior of queries. Here is my code:

```
app.post('/insert', async function(req, res, next)
{
    var jsondata    =   req.body;   
    var flag        =   0;
    var offset      =   0;
    async.whilst(
        function test()
        {  
            return flag == 0; 
        },
        function chk(callback) 
        {
            connection.query('SELECT nlc,id,user_id,coin_id FROM tbl_buy WHERE `type`="buy" AND `status`="available" AND coin_id="'+jsondata.coinid+'" AND order_type="market" order by id ASC LIMIT '+offset+',1',function (error,results, fields)
            { 
                if(results.length > 0)
                {
                    connection.query('SELECT tbl_buy.* from (select tbl_buy.*, (@sum := @sum + nlc) as cume_stock from tbl_buy cross join (select @sum := 0) params  WHERE tbl_buy.type="sell" AND tbl_buy.status="available" AND tbl_buy.user_id!="'+results[0].user_id+'" AND tbl_buy.coin_id="'+jsondata.coinid+'" AND tbl_buy.order_type="market" order by id ) tbl_buy where cume_stock-nlc < "'+results[0].nlc+'"', async function (error,results_arr, fields)
                    {
                        if(results_arr.length > 0) 
                        {
                            flag = 1;
                            // here both methods execute simultaneously instead of one after another
                            await executeOrder(results,results_arr);  // this method contains mysql queries
                            await executeLimitOrders(jsondata.coinid); // this method contains mysql queries
                            callback();         
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            offset++;
                            callback()
                        }     
                });
                }
            });
        },
        function callback(err) {
            if(err)
            console.log(err);

            console.log('Job completed..!!');
            //executeLimitOrders(jsondata.coinid);  
        }
    );
})
```

Please , sugguest some proper way of executing the mysql queries in sequence.After executing all functions finally i want to call another method again containing the mysql code.

Comment: The [`async`](http://caolan.github.io/async/) library you are using is a different thing from `async/await`. Also using the import name as `async` is going to override that keyword. If you want Promise resolution with `async/await` then you are better off looking for conversion of the "callback" variants of your library to using Promises instead.

Comment: Why is async.whilst mixed with native async? You cannot expect that non-promise callbacks will behave properly with promises, because they aren't supposed to. Stick to promisified libraries wherever possible like https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql or promisify them yourself.

Comment: async.whilst is used to execute the code repeated, until the flag is not set to 1.Here , I want to execute the code in loop unless i do not get the result.

Comment: @bhayashree You could use `while` itself with async..await and avoid callback hell.

Comment: i tired it using it do while loop and used async for app.post method like **app.post('/insert', async function(req, res, next)** and await to both methods **await  executeOrder(results,results_arr);**
**await  executeLimitOrders(jsondata.coinid);**.But while executes  infinity time without execute the mysql code due to asynchronous behaviour.

Comment: Your code doesn't contain these fuctions, so it's impossible to say what's wrong. You need to use `@` in order for users to receive notifications.

Comment: It would be better if you combine both queries into a join and minimalize the databases calles needed